# T-SQL to Oracle: Complicated Table Column

Tags: sql, oracle, t-sql, ddl, oracle12c

I'd like to convert the following table to PL-SQL.

```
CREATE TABLE [SchemaName].[TableName] (
    [value]         VARBINARY (2000) NULL,
    [valueAsString] AS               (CONVERT([nvarchar](1000),[value],0))
);
```

Has anyone an idea on how to recreate the `valueAsString` pseudo column in PL?

Comment: I believe you want `[valueAsString]` as a virtual column.

Comment: `varbinary` would be `BLOB` in Oracle, but I don't think you can easily convert that to a sensible character representation (especially not as a computed column). But the whole table doesn't really make sense to me. What are you storing in that `value` column? If you need that as a character value, then why don't you use `CLOB` right away?

Comment: Absolutely. I've got that part figured out. Now I'm working on alternatives to CONVERT. The VARBINARY column is now LONG RAW and I'm not sure that Oracle's TO_CHAR function likes this type.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm not sure. This is an existing system I'm working on.

Comment: `LONG RAW` is deprecated. Do **not** use it. Use `BLOB` instead.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be

```
HUSQVIK@hq_pdb_tcp> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION convert_raw_to_nvarchar(bin RAW) RETURN NVARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC
  2  IS
  3  BEGIN
  4     RETURN utl_raw.cast_to_nvarchar2(bin);
  5  END;
  6  /

Function created.

HUSQVIK@hq_pdb_tcp> CREATE TABLE SchemaName.TableName (
  2      value         RAW(2000) NULL,
  3      valueAsString AS (convert_raw_to_nvarchar(value))
  4  );

Table created.

HUSQVIK@hq_pdb_tcp> insert into tablename (value) values (utl_raw.cast_to_raw(n'123344čřžžýřžý'));

1 row created.

HUSQVIK@hq_pdb_tcp> select * from tablename;

VALUE                                                        VALUEASSTRING
------------------------------------------------------------ --------------------
00310032003300330034003400630072007A007A00EC0072007A00EC     123344cržžýržý
```

If the limit of the binary column is 2000 bytes BLOB is not needed.

`utl_raw.cast_to_nvarchar2` is not deterministic unfortunately so it needs to be wrapped into deterministic function to be usable in table definition.

But I don't like such solution. A view can solve this without schema level function. Also data types suggest you store information using inappropriate data type when you want to always convert binary data into string.